# Is cultura a future participle?

Tags: etymology, derivation, suffixes

Some nouns derived from verbs look like future participles: *cultura* from *colere*, *sepultura* from *sepelire*, *scriptura* from *scribere*…
These do not have a future meaning, but are merely names for the activity associated with the verb.
Are they actually related to the future participle in one way or another?
Or do they just happen to have an unrelated suffix that looks the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gary Miller, in [*Latin Suffixal Derivatives in English and Their Indo-European Ancestry*](https://books.google.com/books?id=7rMUDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA119&lpg=PA119&dq=pictura+cultura+fractura+latin&source=bl&ots=i4lluhDHUA&sig=34PvDXwlJk4or4xuKHOqdg2JKnE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwii1vfOl7fOAhVoBMAKHQEYB3MQ6AEIJDAC#v=onepage&q=pictura%20cultura%20fractura%20latin&f=false) says that **there is no direct relation between nouns formed from verbs with *-ura* and the similar future active participles**.

> Formally, this suffix seems to be an adjectival **-ro-* (fem. **-reh<sub>2</sub>*) extension of nominal **-t(e/o)u-*.... While *-tura* bears a close resemblance to the future active participle *-turus, -a, -um*, there is no simple way the two can be related. (p. 118)

He gives three reasons for this lack of resemblance:

1. **Temporal difference**

> Since the future active participle *futurus, -a, -um* is older than the substantivized neuter *futurum*, pl. *futura*, the nominal suffix could not have spawned the future participle. (ibid)

2. **Differences in stem formation**: Two examples:

   1. FAP *pariturus* vs. noun *partura*
   2. FAP *stātūrus* vs. noun *statūra* (short a)
3. **Similarity with other nominal suffixes**

> The nominal suffix patterns with *-or/-tor* (etc.) in having an older form *-ura* beside *-tura* (build on stem II). (ibid)

An example of this would be *figura* and *fictura*.

Comment: I hadn't realized that there is a difference in stem. Do you know how to find the stem for the derivative? (If there is an answer but it doesn't fit in a comment, let me know and I'll ask it as a separate question.)

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure--Miller is my authority here. Vowel quantities were never my strong suit :)

Comment: I asked it as [a separate question](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1363/79) in case someone knows.