# Stem for derivatives like figura, statura and cultura

Tags: classical-latin, grammar-choice, conjugation, derivation

I learned in [a recent question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1353/79) that derived nouns like *figura*, *statura* and *cultura* do not always look like the future participle but are actually formed from a different stem.
Examples of differences: *figura/fictura*, *stătura/stātura*, *partura/partitura*.

Is there a rule for stem formation in this derivation?
The nouns do not (always) come from the perfect participle stem.
That is, if I want to productively derive more such nouns, how do I do it?

Comment: I can't find *partitura* on the Perseus dictionary tool, nor *paritura* (which is the form mentioned in the previous question).

Comment: (I mean that I can't find *paritura* as a noun, rather than a fut. ppl.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a general answer to this -- the forms you cite appear to be individual random exceptions to the rule.

The long *ā* of the fut. ppl. *stātūrus* is historically secondary. The pf. ppl. *stătus* has short *ă*, which is etymologically expected (it's the reflex of an Indo-European laryngeal, like in *dătus*); *stātūrus* must therefore be an analogical form, based on the long *ā* that appears in practically all first-conjugation verbs. The noun *stătūra*, not being a verb form, presumably escaped this analogy.

As for *par(i)tūra*: there seems to be no noun of either form in Lewis and Short. A [PackHum search](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=partura) for *partūra* finds only one example, in Varro; the normal fut. ppl. form seems to be *paritūrus*. This fut. ppl. is slightly irregular in that it does not share the stem of the pf. ppl. *partus*; the latter presumably results from vowel syncope between coronal consonants, which is a common phenomenon (though not a wholly regular sound change) in Latin. In this case the fut. ppl., maybe because it's a less common form, evaded the sound change and remained regular (or was analogically reformed).

*Figūra* is the only really anomalous form in that it obviously cannot be derived from the stem of the fut. ppl.: in other words the suffix here is *-ūr-* rather than *-tūr-*. It seems to be the only such example; Weiss's historical grammar of Latin lists it specifically as such in the section about derived nouns in *-tūra-* (I don't have the book handy at the moment so can't cite the page).