# Rise and Conquer?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

How would one say “Rise and Conquer” in Latin?

As in “I rise from the ashes and conquer the world”.

I have found several translations but would like to get confirmation.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add the translations that you found?

Answer (score 5):

The whole sentence "I will rise from the ashes and conquer the whole world" would be: *Ex cinere surgam et toto orbe potiar.*

I used the future tense here, because the sentence appears to speak about future events, and it seems more natural to use the future tense (both in English and Latin). Instead of *surgam*, you can also say *reviviscam* (come back to life).

*Potiri* does mean "conquer," but is more comparable to "capture." The problem being, in order to get to the shorter version you seek, just like in English it would sound strange to say "I will rise and capture" -- prompting the question "Capture what?" -- it would likewise sound strange to use *potiar* without an object. So I would recommend for that to use *vincere* instead, which means "conquer" in the sense of "be victorious, overcome." With this we get:

*Surgam et vincam.*

Incidentally, this also means "May I rise and conquer" (not as a question, of course, but expressing a hope or wish). For better or worse, the present subjunctive and the future are indistuingishable in the first person singular, at least in the third conjugation, which both of these verbs happen to belong to.

(I was about to suggest *Surgiturus et victurus sum*, but that would have an [ambiguity of its own](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16220/is-victurus-a-future-participle-of-vivo-and-vinco), sigh...).