# Are future active participles of deponent verbs used in place of future passive participles? Why?

Tags: grammar-choice, participle, deponent-verbs

In form, *nātūrus* is a future *active* participle of the (deponent) verb *nāscor* – which otherwise only appears in *passive* forms – and is used to mean *about to rise* and, taken literally, *about to be born*, at least according to [wiktionary/nātūrus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/naturus#Latin). However, if *nāscor* literally means *to be born*, shouldn’t *nātūrus* rather mean *about to bear* or *about to give birth*?

Wouldn’t it make more sense to use a future passive participles, such as *nāscendus* instead of *nātūrus*? How can *nātūrus* carry the same meaning rather than the dual one?

Does this happen in general with other deponent verbs? Why?

*Remark*. The future active participle actually seems to be *nāscitūrus*, according to Asteroides’ comment below. Wiktionary seems to have it wrong as of now. It also has an entry on [wiktionary/nāscitūrus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nasciturus).

Comment: I asked a similar question whose answers might be helpful: [What is the difference in meaning/usage between “nasciturus” and “nascendus”?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/10679/what-is-the-difference-in-meaning-usage-between-nasciturus-and-nascendus) The future active participle form of *nāscor* is actually *nāscitūrus*, as far as I know--I can't find the form *nātūrus* in [any dictionary other than Wiktionary](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/naturus), only the noun *nātūra,* which ends in a distinct [noun-forming suffix](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1353).

Comment: @Asteroides That's a good point! I updated the example verb in my answer to be the regular *arbitrari* to avoid the slight irregularity of *nasci*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same happens with all deponent verbs in Latin.

The Latin participle system is defective for a transitive verb like *amare*:

|  | Active | Passive |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Past** | — | *amatus* |
| **Present** | *amans* | (*amandus*) |
| **Future** | *amaturus* | (*amandus*) |

The gerundive is not really a participle, although it can play roles similar to the present or future passive participle.
I advice against calling it the future passive participle.
I prefer to say that three of the six participles are simply missing.

For a deponent verb the two voices can be conflated to create a complete system of participles:

|  | Deponent |
| --- | --- |
| **Past** | *arbitratus* |
| **Present** | *arbitrans* |
| **Future** | *arbitraturus* |

(As pointed out in a comment, the future participle of *nasci* is somewhat irregularly *nasciturus* rather than *naturus*. See [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/10679/79) for more discussion on the matter. Therefore I changed my example from *nasci* to *arbitrari*.)

The past participle comes from the passive side, the present and future ones from the active side.
The personal forms all come from passive (unless the verb is semideponent like *gaudeo, gavisus sum*) but participles come from both voices.
It is indeed weird, but active participles are used for both present and future for deponents.
Deponent verbs should not be seen as passive forms of a transitive verb but as independent verbs; if there was a verb *nascere*, "to give birth", the semantics of *na(sci)turus* would be different, but there is no such verb.
The lack of corresponding active forms is a defining feature of deponent verbs.
There is no need to use the gerundive to supplement the participle system.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there an inherent aspect of the primary suffix *-tūr* for the formation of the future active participle that makes this a bit more intuitive? I was speculating that it just might relate to the suffix *-tōr* for constructing a nomen agens …

Comment: @k.stm I'm glad if it helped! I'm not aware of anything that would make it more intuitive. I would treat this as one of the weird things to just accept, but I'd be glad to learn if there's more structure behind it. You can always ask a separate question about etymology of the future participle. We might already have it on the site somewhere.

Comment: A side note, probably already known to and irrelevant to asker and answerer alike: the gerundive of a deponent verb has the normal passive meaning (pretending to be from a non-deponent verb), e.g. Cicero: *verendum est* "it must be feared". The deponent gerund has an active meaning (just like the participles of present and future).

Comment: @Cerberus Just a qualification (perhaps a minor one for many people but perhaps not for you) related to your claim that "the gerundive of a deponent verb (like _verendum est_) has the normal passive meaning ('it must be feared')". For a recent criticism of the traditional passive analysis of the gerundive + _esse_ construction, see this descriptive (not technical!) paper by Danesi et al. (2017) https://biblio.ugent.be/publication/8522423/file/8522426.pdf , published in _Indogermanische Forschungen_ 122.1.

Comment: See their conclusion on p. 24: "In conclusion, the GER+(NOM+)DAT construction is structurally and semantically very different from a passive construction. In fact, the passive analysis of the GER+(NOM+)DAT construction appears quite simplistic and not properly rooted in the actual properties of the construction itself. The passive analysis should therefore be abandoned as such, and following this, the traditional description of the dative argument as being “dative of agent”".