# 'Concepturus' and 'nasciturus' in legal terminology

Tags: grammar-choice, legal-latin

When speaking of the rights of and refering to the one to be conceived in Law we use "concepturus"

Which is the future active participle.

If we wanted to correctly speak of and refer to the one to be conceived shouldn't we use concipiendus (the passive participle)?

Are we actually refering to the one about to conceive; the future mother?
Isn't the mother always feminine why don't we use conceptura if we are referring to the mother?

Edit follow up question (also posted as a reply in an answer [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16661/use-of-participles-in-legal-terminology/16666#comment34619_16666)

**Isn't the use of nasciturus (naturus) wrong? Shouldn't it too be nascendus instead? I never understood "morituri te salutant". Why not moriendus? How can the future active participle be used in the place of future passive participle?**

Comment: Can you add a link to your question, leading to a passage containing _concepturus_ in this sense?

Comment: Regarding the edit, you might find the answers to some previous questions about *nasciturus* helpful: mine here ([What is the difference in meaning/usage between “nasciturus” and “nascendus”?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/10679/what-is-the-difference-in-meaning-usage-between-nasciturus-and-nascendus)) and k.stm's here ([Are future active participles of deponent verbs used in place of future passive participles? Why?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/15147))

Answer (score 2):

***Concipior*** 'to be conceived' appears to think of itself as a Deponent Verb according to [*Liber Primus, or, A First Book of Latin Exercises*](https://archive.org/details/liberprimusoraf02danagoog/page/n127/mode/2up?q=concipior)
by Joseph Dana, A. M. (1827). p128 of 202 (= print 125)
[image: Concipior]

The rule for participles of deponent verbs is from [the National Archive course:](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/latin/stage-2-latin/lessons/lesson-22-deponent-and-semi-deponent-verbs/)

> Deponent verbs have participles, formed in the same way as for normal
> verbs and the meaning is always active.
>
> For example:
>
> The future participle for sequor, sequi, secutus sum (3) ‘to follow’
> is secuturus, -a, -um ‘about to follow’.

Comment: It looks like the plain-text version was confusingly laid out. It actually says that _concipio_ is "to conceive" and _concipior_ is "to be conceived". I updated the link to a format that's easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

The use of *concepturus* for a child that is not yet conceived is quite rare. Using Google, I find a handful of Spanish and Italian sources, such as [this Italian legal dictionary](https://www.brocardi.it/C/concepturus.html):

> Il termine designa colui che non è stato ancora concepito

In many places I found the term goes along with another term, [*nasciturus*](https://www.brocardi.it/N/nasciturus.html), a child that has been conceived but not yet born.

The future participle *concepturus* does indeed not mean “about to be conceived,” it means “about to conceive,” and I might add, if we are indeed talking about the conception of a child, it is an impossibility, because only the mother conceives a child, so if anything, it should be *conceptura*.

I can only conclude that this is a mistake brought about by the parallel with *nasciturus*. *Nasci*, with the irregular future participle *nasciturus*, is a deponent verb meaning “to be born.” Do not be irritated by the fact that the usual English translation is passive, that is arguably just a peculiarity of the English language. Thus *nasciturus* means “about to be born,” (nascituro also seems to be a common Italian term for “unborn child”) and it must have seemed logical to lawyers that a person about to be conceived would then be a *concepturus*.

Comment: Isn't the use of nasciturus (naturus) wrong? Shouldn't it too be nascendus instead? I never understood "morituri te salutant". Why not moriendus? How can the future active participle be used in the place of future passive participle?

Comment: No, it should not be *nascendus*! The gerundive retains its passive meaning even in deponent verbs. Thus it cannot be used with intransitive verbs, which *nasci* is (I cannot “be born my neighbour” etc.) except in impersonal use (*nunc est nascendum* = “it's time to be born” or whatever). As an aside, the gerundive has a rather tenuous connection with the future, plus it already has a perfectly nice name (gerundive), so I personally prefer not to call it a future passive participle.

Comment: How does that work? What happens with deponent verbs? Active becomes Passive and Passibe become impersonal or unusable? How can I recognize a deponent verb? When I encounter the future active participle of a deponent verb will it always carry the meaning of a future passive participle? What happens with the gerundive and it's connection with the future; why is it tenuous?

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos That sounds like several more questions. I especially like "How can I recognize a deponent verb?" The quick explanation of deponent verbs, though, is that they have passive form but active meaning; their participles all have active meaning (except the gerundive).

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos Several good links regarding deponents habe already been given. As for the gerundive, well, take for example the sentence "Scelera Catliniae non sunt ferenda" -- what does this future active participle have to do with the future? But this is indeed a whole different can of worms...